# Poco::Foundation Target Not found with conan

Tags: c++, cmake, poco-libraries, conan

I want to build a little Library and link it against the Poco Foundation Library.
I use Conan to install Poco with the `cmake_find_package` generator.

This is my `conanfile.py`:

```py
from conans import ConanFile

class ExamplePluginConan(ConanFile):
    settings = "os", "compiler", "build_type", "arch"
    requires = "poco/1.11.0"
    generators = "cmake_find_package"
    default_options = {
        "poco:shared": True, 
        "poco:enable_active_record": False,
        "poco:enable_crypto": False,
        "poco:enable_data": False,
        "poco:enable_data_mysql": False,
        "poco:enable_data_postgresql": False,
        "poco:enable_data_sqlite": False,
        "poco:enable_jwt": False,
        "poco:enable_mongodb": False,
        "poco:enable_net": False,
        "poco:enable_netssl": False,
        "poco:enable_redis": False,
        "poco:enable_zip": False,
        }

    def imports(self):
        if self.settings.build_type == "Debug":
            self.copy("*.dll", dst="bin/Debug", src="bin", root_package="poco")
        elif self.settings.build_type == "Release":
            if self.settings.os == "Windows":
                self.copy("*.dll", dst="bin/Release", src="bin", root_package="poco")
            elif self.settings.os == "Linux":
                self.copy("*.so*", dst="bin", src="lib", root_package="poco")
```

And this is my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

if(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR STREQUAL CMAKE_BINARY_DIR)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Do not build in-source. Please remove CMakeCache.txt and the CMakeFiles/ directory. Then build out-of-source")
endif()

project("ExamplePlugin" VERSION 1.0.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
set(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)

option(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS "Build shared (dynamic) libraries." ON)


add_library(ExamplePlugin)
add_library("jd::ExamplePlugin" ALIAS ExamplePlugin)

target_sources(ExamplePlugin
                    PUBLIC
                    include/ExamplePlugin/ExamplePlugin.hpp
                    PRIVATE
                    src/ExamplePlugin.cpp
)

find_package(Poco)

if(NOT TARGET Poco::Poco)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Target  Not Found ")
endif()

target_link_libraries(ExamplePlugin PUBLIC jd::Core Poco::Foundation)

target_include_directories(ExamplePlugin PUBLIC "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>"
                            "$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:$<INSTALL_PREFIX>/${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}>"
                            PRIVATE "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src>"
)               

if(NOT BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
    string(TOUPPER ExamplePlugin PROJECT_NAME_UPPER)
    set_target_properties(ExamplePlugin PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS -D${PROJECT_NAME_UPPER}_STATIC)
endif()


set_target_properties(ExamplePlugin PROPERTIES SOVERSION 1 VERSION 1.0.0)
set_target_properties(ExamplePlugin PROPERTIES 
                    ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib"
                    LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin"
                    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin"
)
set_target_properties(ExamplePlugin PROPERTIES DEBUG_POSTFIX "d")

include(GenerateExportHeader)
string(TOUPPER ExamplePlugin PROJECT_NAME_UPPER)
generate_export_header(ExamplePlugin
    EXPORT_FILE_NAME ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/ExamplePlugin/export.hpp
    EXPORT_MACRO_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME_UPPER}_EXPORT
    STATIC_DEFINE ${PROJECT_NAME_UPPER}_STATIC
)
```

This always gives me the Error that the Target `Poco::Foundation` was not found:

> CMake Error at ExamplePlugin/CMakeLists.txt:20 (add_library):
> Target "ExamplePlugin" links to target "Poco::Foundation" but the target
> was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
> target, or an ALIAS target is missing?

It only works if i specify the `Poco::Poco` Target. But this will link my Library against all the Poco Libraries (like the  `Net`, `Utils`, `JSON` etc)

Is there a way to only link against the `Poco::Foundation` Part?

Answer (score 0):

At the time i posted the question it was not possible. But there was an update to the `Poco` Package in the Conan Center and now it is possible to only link against a specific target like `poco::foundation`

Comment: Yes, the feature in Conan is called "components" (same as in CMake), this migth be a useful link for other readers: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/creating_packages/package_information.html#using-components